# Tkinter combobox callback infinite loop?

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, callback

Struggling with this.  My code never returns after executing callback method to the class method that made that call.

I call combox setup from 'select_sheet'. The combox method runs.  The callback method is bound, and executes when an option from drop down is selected.  But then the cursor dissapears after jumping to `__init__.py` 'mainloop'.

---

```
class SelectSheet():
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.fp = file_path
        self.selected_sheet = ''

    def get_sheet(self) -> None:

        # Create tkinter Window
        self.master_win = tk.Tk()                                
        # Primary window to hold widgets
        self.master_win.title("Tk dropdown example")
        self.master_win.geometry('400x100')

        # Label: Title
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.master_win, text="Combobox Widget",   # Label text for title
                  background='green', foreground="white",
                  font=("Times New Roman", 15)).grid(row=0, column=1)
        # Label: Drop-Down
        self.label1 = ttk.Label(self.master_win, text="Select the Month :",    # Label
                  font=("Times New Roman", 10)).grid(column=0, row=5, padx=10, pady=25)

        # Combobox creation.
        self.cbox_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.cbox_master = ttk.Combobox(self.master_win, width=27, textvariable=self.cbox_var)

        # Drop down list
        self.cbox_master['values'] = (' January',                
                                  ' February',
                                  ' March',
                                  ' April')
        self.cbox_master.grid(column=1, row=5)
        self.cbox_master.current()
        self.cbox_master.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.callback)       
        print("entering mainloop\n")
        self.master_win.mainloop()

    def callback(self, event):                                   
        self.selected_sheet = self.cbox_master.get()
        self.master_win.destroy()
        # It goes to __init.py def mainloop and never returns    

    def select_sheet(self) -> str():
        self.combox_window()
        # It never comes back to this point
        return self.selected_sheet

ss = SelectSheet(xl_path)        
gs = ss.select_sheet()
```

Does anyone know why the code never returns to select_sheet method?

Comment: This code won't run as posted. You haven't defined `xl_path` or `combox_window`.

Comment: @ Bryan - Thank you.  I was just about to fix all that when in trying to do so I figured out the problem.  I had an initial root window in another part of the program that had not been 'destroyed' and so my guess is that there was some kind of conflict.  I believe somewhere in memory someone stated that tkinter only allows one root window at a time.

Comment: It allows more than one root window, but the side effects of doing so isn't obvious. As a rule of thumb you should never have more than one.